# Accidentally made a partial wireframe. Does anyone know a fix?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender and I stumbled into a problem where my model suddenly became partially wireframe when I deleted some edges. Is there a way to get my faces to fill themselves back out?

So far all I've done was create a cylinder, add some edge loops, scale said edge loops, then select every second vertical line and delete them to reduce poly count. When I deleted the edges, the model turned into this:

[image]

Comment: When removing extra geometry you don't delete it but dissolve (X > Limited Dissolve or X > Dissolve Edges or X > Edge Loops). As to your question try to select all and press F to fill new faces.

Answer (score 1):

You have [deleted](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#delete) the edges.

> [Delete Edges] Deletes any edges in the current selection. Removes any faces that the edge shares with it.

As you can read in the manual entry, the adjacent faces are removed.

You probably want to [dissolve the edges](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/deleting.html#dissolve-edges), since this will retain the faces.

> [Dissolve Edges] Removes edges sharing two faces (joining those faces).

However, since you have already deleted the edges you will have extra vertices between to adjacent edges. This would have not happened with the dissolve operation.

You can box select <kbd>B</kbd> the vertices. Then dissolve them <kbd>X</kbd> > *Dissolve Vertices*. After that you recreate the faces by selecting all <kbd>A</kbd> and filling with <kbd>F</kbd>.